# My CPU fan stop working on dell Inspiron 1545

Tags: dell, cpu, fan, inspiron, temperature

After installing Ubuntu 12.04 my CPU temperature gets abnormally high: 80-86 °C. I saw that the CPU fan isn't running. Is it possible for this problem to be caused by Ubuntu or not?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it caused by Ubuntu. Please check

- Your BIOS setting.
- Reset it to default.
- Update your BIOS.

It it does not work then you have problem with your FAN. (I think)!

Please let me know the update.

Comment: Or see [here](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_control_fan_speed), how to control your CPU fan.

Answer (score -2):

When my laptop g6 does that I took a needle and rotate it manually then I start the computer again and it works again, it happen twice now.